# Python how to merge to dictionaries together with a range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of values

```
list = ["apple","red","oranges","orange","grapes","purple"]
```

and list of columns:

```
columns = ["fruit","color"]
```

I would like to create a merged dictionary together to look like

```
["fruit": "apple", "colour": "red"]
["fruit": "oranges", "colour": "orange"]
["fruit": "grapes", "colour": "purple"]

empty_item = dict([(i, None) for i in columns])
item = empty_item
for x in range(item):
```

I have the following above code but can't figure out the rest

Edit ---

Thank you for the below solutions they worked but I'm looking to split my merged dictionaries into all separate lines so

```
["fruit": "apple", "colour": "red"] -- (separate line, line 1)
["fruit": "oranges", "colour": "orange"] -- (separate line, line 2)
["fruit": "grapes", "colour": "purple"] -- (separate line, line 3)
```

Comment: that's not correct dictionary syntax, also don't call a list "list"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension within a list comprehension like so:

```
l = ["apple","red","oranges","orange","grapes","purple"]
columns = ["fruit","color"]
colLen = len(columns)
res = [{columns[j]: l[i * colLen + j] for j in range(colLen)} 
          for i in range(len(l) // colLen)]
print(res)
# [{'fruit': 'apple', 'color': 'red'}, {'fruit': 'oranges', 'color': 'orange'}, {'fruit': 'grapes', 'color': 'purple'}]
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/AgDTea)

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not correct syntax. I assume you want a list of dictionaries in that format though. The code below will do the trick.

```
lst = ["apple","red","oranges","orange","grapes","purple"]
columns = ["fruit","color"]
lstDicts = [{columns[0]:fruit,columns[1]:color} for fruit, color in zip(*[iter(lst)]*2)]
```

the code iterates through `lst` two elements at a time, assigning the first element to `fruit` and the second the `color`. Also we can implement list comprehension to create a list of dictionaries.
output

```
[{'fruit': 'apple', 'color': 'red'}, 
{'fruit': 'oranges', 'color': 'orange'},
 {'fruit': 'grapes', 'color': 'purple'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution that'll make you cry of joy:

```py
values = ["apple","red","oranges","orange","grapes","purple"]
columns = ["fruit","color"]

print([{key: value for key, value in zip(columns, pair)} 
        for pair in zip(values[:-1:2], values[1::2])])
```